# Entity collection checking contain any string

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I get the entity collection using stored proc.
I want check the string value which is contain in that collection or not.
How can do it

code is below

```
var objattendance = context.Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates(datefrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), dateto.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), emp);
 string date = CurrentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I want to check the `date` is contain in the `objattendance`

Comment: What datastructure does `Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates` return?

Comment: my stored proc is
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates]

 @datefrom nvarchar(250),
 @dateto nvarchar(250),
 @empid int

AS
BEGIN


select AM.record_Id,AM.employee_Id as employee_Id,CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111) as date from 
tblAttendanceMaster AM 

where AM.employee_Id=@empid and  CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111) between CONVERT(varchar(10),@datefrom,111)

and CONVERT(varchar(10),@dateto,111)

END

GO`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend NOT converting the date value to a string in the stored procedure. `CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111)` should be just `AM.date`.

Then you can write:

```
var containsDate = objattendance.Any(x => x.date.Date == CurrentDate.Date);
```

Comment: Thanks.It is working but have a problem

I cant iterate this code.getting error
as
`The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.`

Comment: Add a `.ToList()` after the database call to the stored procedure. `var objattendance = context.Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates(datefrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), dateto.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), emp).ToList();`